# I met some problems with using ranged based loops to calculate sum of array by using pointers and functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

Everything was ok until I passed the array as a pointer into the "total" function.

An error occured after I tried to used auto i to calculate sum of array -

```
int total = 0;

for(auto i : *arr) {
  total+=i;
}
```

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLawa.png)

```
    // This is my codes
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int total(int *);
    
    int main () {
        
      int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    
      cout << "Displaying array:\n";
    
      for(auto i : arr) {
        cout << i << " ";
      } 
      
      cout << "\n\nThe sum of array: " << total(arr);
        
      return 0;
    }
    
    int total(int *arr) {
      int total = 0;
      
      for(auto i : *arr) {   //where the error occured
        total+=i;
      }  
      
      return total;
    }
```

Comment: the picture you added for the output doesn't line up with the code in your question description

Answer (score 0):

```
int total(int *arr)
```

The parameter to this function is a pointer to an integer. `arr` is an `int *`, nothing more, nothing else. That's what the above declaration means in C++.

```
    for(auto i : *arr) {   //where the error occured
```

And the error is because range iteration is defined only for containers or other objects for which `std::begin` and `std::end` is specialized.

Neither `int` (what `*arr` resolves to), nor `int *`, meets those requirements. Hence the compilation error.

It is true that an array was passed into this function, for the `arr` parameter. This is true, but irrelevant. In this function this is only an `int *`, a single, lonely, boring pointer to an integer. Nothing more, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you supply an array as an argument to a function, the array decays into a pointer to the first element in the array.

In here, this `arr` has no knowledge about the extent of the `arr[5]` you passed as an argument:

```
int total(int *arr) {
    // arr is a pointer to a single `int`
}
```

Here are two versions preserving the knowledge about the extent of the array.

1. A pointer to an `int[5]`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int total(int (*)[5]);

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    std::cout << "Displaying array:\n";

    for (auto i : arr) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n\nThe sum of array: " << total(&arr); // & takes its address

    return 0;
}

int total(int (*arr)[5]) {
    int total = 0;

    for (auto i : *arr) {  // derefrence the pointer to get an int[5]
        total += i;
    }

    return total;
}
```

2. A reference to an `int[5]`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int total(int (&)[5]);

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    std::cout << "Displaying array:\n";

    for (auto i : arr) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n\nThe sum of array: " << total(arr);

    return 0;
}

int total(int (&arr)[5]) {
    int total = 0;

    for (auto i : arr) { // arr is a reference to an int[5]
        total += i;
    }

    return total;
}
```